# How to remove text from a pattern in a certain column

Tags: bash, tabular

I have a table file such as :

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore    strand

scaffold    EOG091B09QV:/path/path/Z    xx  a   1:8830-20153    74.3    144 0   1
scaffold    EOG091B09QV:/path/path/A    x   a   1:8830-20153    100.0   93  0   0
scaffold    EOG091B09QV:/path/path/Q    x   a   1:8830-20153    41.3    189 49  3
scaffold    EOG091B09QV:/path/path/U    x   a   1:8830-20153    87.5    48  6   0
scaffold    EOG091B09QV:/path/path/K    x   a   1:8830-20153    100.0   60  0   0
```

And the idea is simply to remove in the column sseqid the text after `:` 
and get:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore    strand

scaffold    EOG091B09QV xx  a   1:8830-20153    74.3    144 0   1
scaffold    EOG091B09QV x   a   1:8830-20153    100.0   93  0   0
scaffold    EOG091B09QV x   a   1:8830-20153    41.3    189 49  3
scaffold    EOG091B09QV x   a   1:8830-20153    87.5    48  6   0
scaffold    EOG091B09QV x   a   1:8830-20153    100.0   60  0   0
```

I know that `cut -f 1 -d ":"` matches`_species_strand_H.m8` can work but not in column specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is a good choice to handle column based text:

```
awk 'sub(/:.*/,"",$2)+7' file
```

will do the job: "remove the `:.*` from the 2nd column.

Comment: I like this solution better than my own. It's shorter and clearer. However, it replaces all whitespace between columns with a single space character (but only on lines that it modifies). This may or may not be an issue for OP. If the multiple spaces in the input file were there intentionally for formatting purposes, that might be a problem.

Comment: @MikeHolt if format is an issue,  one can try pipe to `|column -t`

Answer (score 1):

I prefere Perl for such things:

```
cat inputfile | perl -ne '@in=split(/\s/);$in[1]=~s/:(.*)$//;print(join(" ",@in));print "\n"'
```

perl -ne loops over each input-line, split the line to an array, replace the stuff in the second element and join the array together.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sed` fairly easily:

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+\s+[^:[:space:]]+):\S+/\1/g' filename
```

The part inside the parentheses matches the first column, the whitespace between the first and second columns, and the portion of the second column up until (but not including) the `:` character. The `:\S+` matches the remainder of the second column. The entire matched portion of the line is then replace with only the part inside the parentheses, which is represented by `\1`.